# Symfony2 removeListener does not find my listener

Tags: php, symfony, events

I'm having problems removing a listener that I create dynamically:

```
public function renderMyData($dataA, $dataB)
{
    $key = $dataA->getKey();
    $this->callables[$key] = function ($event) use ($dataA, $dataB) {
        $this->onTableRendered($dataA, $dataB, $event->getAProperty());)
    };

    $this->eventDispatcher->addListener(
        Events::TABLE_RENDERED,
        $this->callables[$key]
    );
}
```

I do this mainly because I want to throw my own event on `Events::TABLE_RENDERED` and add `$dataA` and `$dataB` on it.

Because this `renderMyData` can be called with different values for `$dataA` and `$dataB`, I want the listener to only be called once for each par of data so the first thing I do in `onTableRendered` is to unregister the callable I created.

```
public function onTableRendered($dataA, $dataB, $aProperty)
{
    $key = $dataA->getKey();
    $this->eventDispatcher->removeListener(
       Events::TABLE_RENDERED,
       $this->callables[$key]
    );

    // Create new event
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(
         new MyNewEvent($dataA, $dataB, $aProperty)
    );
}
```

However Symfony is unable to remove my callable from its list of listeners. I debugged symfony (using v2.6.11) until reaching this part of `\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher`

```
foreach ($this->listeners[$eventName] as $priority => $listeners) {
    if (false !== ($key = array_search($listener, $listeners, true))) {
        unset($this->listeners[$eventName][$priority][$key], $this->sorted[$eventName]);
    }
}
```

Where I can see that my callback is inside `$listeners`, but `array_search` returns false...

Am I creating my callback wrongly?